# Удаленный просмотр логов на centos

Tags: apache, centos, администрирование, tomcat, vim

Проблема такая. Есть виртуальный сервер, на нем `centOS` и развернуто веб-приложение (на `tomcat`'e). Рабочая машина у меня на `Windows`.

Надо `как то просматривать логи приложения` (да и БД с сервером бы не помешало), желательно в режиме онлайн и удобочитаемым форматированием.

Я разобрался как делать подключение к машине через `PuTTY`, нормально управляю сервером, бд и файловой системой. Опыта в данном области практически нет, посадили за рабочие место и дерзай, спросить не у кого (я один программист/администратор/верстальщик в штате). Пока что просто выкачиваю логи и смотрю на своей машине уже. Читал про vim, не разобрался. Везде написано с тем уклоном, что читатель уже имеет какой то опыт администрирования.

**Подскажите пожалуйста на каких машинах и что надо поставить и в каком порядке запускать.** Или ссылку на отличный гайд (поисковик что то не то выдает).

Comment: Если немного подучить python, то можно использовать, например, [fabric](http://adw0rd.com/2012/8/14/python-fabric/). Это инструмент деплоя (а не просмотра логов в режиме онлайн), но никто не мешает использовать для своих нужд. Например, вывели часть логов, нашли там ошибки, сохранили в файл (`run("tail -n 1000 /var/log/log.txt | grep 'error' > /tmp/error.log'`) и скачали себе (`get('/tmp/error.log', 'error.log')`). Дополнительно можно поставить [fabtools](https://fabtools.readthedocs.org) и работать с базой и прочим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите через `PuTTY` и установите `mc`

`mc` это программа в виде `TotalCommender` легче будет просматривать и управлять

[Как установить Midnight Commander в CentOS?](http://yournet.kz/blog/os/linux/kak-ustanovit-midnight-commander-v-centos)

Comment: Мне кажется, не совсем верный путь просматривать логи через mcedit. Думаю, второй ответ (про multitail) больше подойдёт. Ну или можно просто использовать команду tail, а окно терминала разбить на несколько виртуальных окон через тот же tmux...

Comment: согласень, tail тоже отличный инструмент если правитьно использовать

Answer (score 2):

есть такая утилитка, называется multitail. Зайдя через putty можно смотреть с помощью этой утилитки несколько файлов, как в разных окнах, так и в одном(перемешанные логи из разных файлов в одном окне)

Comment: multitail расположен на репозитории, не поддерживаемом centos по каким то причинам